# How to make xampp public and accessible?

Tags: networking, xampp

Im trying to make my website public and accessible by anyone. I am using xampp. I dont have a static ip address so i decided to use dynamic dns services. My concern is, to what port should i configure my router to forward connections? What port is used by Xampp?

Thanks in advance. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Quote from xampp home page:

> The default configuration is not good from a securtiy point of view and it's not secure enough for a production environment - please don't use XAMPP in such environment.

I really don't know how to do it but I imagine there is an "Online Mode". Google should yield a simple answer for this.

Any web server on your computer should be listening on port 80. That is the standard port for browsing websites.